# php-cli on IBMi error/notice reporting

Tags: php, printing, ibm-midrange, error-logging, rpg

We have developed a PHP script to build PDF's and send emails which then get called from an RPG program using `QP2SHELL`.  For our developer users the errors go to the standard PHP error log, but for our customer's users it's printing on their default printer.  Our developer profiles use `*WRKSTN` as the printer, and of course the users have an actual printer device.  Is there a way to prevent this from printing through either RPG or PHP?  We are comfortable with suppressing all logs because we have our own logging methods in place.  I have tried in PHP setting `error_reporting(0);` which seemed to have no effect.

Comment: You might try using the `OVRPRTF` CL command to override attributes of the spooled files that get created.  For example, specify `HOLD(*YES)` to keep them from printing.

Comment: As much as I'd like them to have done this programmatically we've set the system-wide default for the spool file (QPRINT) to HLDPRT.  Thanks for the response, though.